# Receive touch events from an UIView from a Nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm sure this is an easy one, yet I need some pointing in the right direction. I have a rather complicated NIB that I would like to have only one view in that nib to listen for touch & multi-touch events. What is the best way of doing so using IBOutlets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would do the following: subclass UIView and implement whichever of the UIResponder touch methods are useful to you:

– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:

Or you could implement these methods in a UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds doable, but what are the implications of subclassing a UIView that is already being loaded from the nib?

Comment: That should be just fine. Just make sure that the nib knows the custom class of your UIView. UIViews (and NSViews) in nibs are generally meant to be instances of a subclass, because a UIView (or NSView) doesn't do a whole lot on its own. Good luck!

Comment: How do you subclass a UIView defined in a nib file?

Comment: What you want to do is write your own subclass, like `EpicJusticeView.h`, `EpicJusticeVice.m`. Then, in your nib file, go to the inspector for your UIView instance, and change it's class to `EpicJusticeView`.